# Which SAS cable to connect an internal HP LTO-5 tape drive?

Tags: hp, sas, tapedrive

I've bought an internal HP Ultrium 3000 LTO 5 tape drive (Model 693416-001) without SAS connection cable.

Being new to SAS I have discovered that there are loads of different types of cable, and I have no idea which the HP drive uses or how to find out.

It doesn't appear on the spec I can find on the HP site - it just says the cable is included!

Can anyone tell me what sort of cable and card type I need for the tape drive, and what sort of controller would be suitable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Internal SAS drives usually have SFF-8482 connectors.

[image]
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_Attached_SCSI#Connectors

Comment: That's that I'd thought - but I just didn't want to order the wrong thing. Thanks!

Comment: @Screwtape No need to comment with thanks. Please mark it as an answer, and/or upvote if it helped.